# cordova: command not found from Jenkins

Tags: macos, cordova, jenkins, terminal

I'm trying to setup Jenkins to build a cordova 3.4 project but I'm getting a 'command not found' error when I try to run 'cordova prepare' as an Execute Shell command in Jenkins. I know cordova is installed on the machine but I don't know how to add it so that Jenkins can find it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Is executable in your `PATH`?

Comment: Mac actually. No its not in my PATH and I don't know how to add it for the jenkins user. I don't have usr/local/bin in my PATH and I don't know how to add it for that user

Answer (score 2):

Best way to modify PATH is to go to Jenkins global (or slave) configuration and add environment variable PATH and it's desired value under "Environment variables" section.

Comment: Please elaborate: What exactly did you do and how did you verify it does not work?

Comment: sorry. I set the PATH to the environment variables in Jenkins and set the path values as a value. Maybe I understand you in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905787/6437038

**TLDR**: add `#!/bin/bash -l` in the beginning of the jenkins job