# Can't run "pod install" in jenkins

Tags: macos, jenkins, cocoapods

My slave machine of Jenkins is Mac 10.8.
Jenkins run job on my slave machine and run shell command of cocoapods below:

```
pod install
```

and got error from console output of Jenkins job, please check below:

```
pod: command not found
```

I tried to run this command "pod install" in local's terminal of this slave machine and gets succeeds.

could you kindly help on me how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30934258/4712174

Answer (score 25):

In my case, my ruby is installed by rvm. I need to load rvm in to find the pod command.

What I did is add this line `#!/bin/bash -l` in the beginning of the jenkins job.

Comment: This worked for me as well! I'm a *nix newbie, could you please explain what this does?

Comment: Daniel: if you type `man bash` in a terminal, you get the manual. In there it says `-l` "makes bash act as ifit had been invoked as a login shell". The login shell worked in OP's case, so this makes it work when called from jenkins.

Comment: This worked with my npm ionic cordova related problem aswell! I just put it in Jenkins execute shell, at the top.

Comment: You saved my day! Fixed all at once: npm, ionic, cordova, pod, fastlane.

Comment: This did not work for me. Pod command is still not found.

Answer (score 15):

Ran into the same problem today, but neither of the solutions worked. What did work was changing the install command.

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

Comment: This worked for me! You can find where that dir is with:
which -a pod

Answer (score 11):

It seems the user with which Jenkins is running is not getting the path to the `pod` command that you are able to *successfully* execute from the Node's command shell. All you need to do is explicitly add the path in `PATH` variable in your Node's *configuration* page. To do this, `Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Select the Node where your job is running > Click on Configure > Enable Node Properties`. Refer the screenshot below:

[image]

Just add the path to your pod command in PATH variable. For ex., if the pod command is present in /usr/bin, then in the *name* field, enter `PATH` and in the *value* field, enter `/usr/bin/:$PATH`

I have not worked on Mac but hopefully, the above command should work there too. If it doesn't work, you can put the following line in *$HOME/.bash_profile* file of the user with which Jenkins is running: `PATH=path_to_pod:$PATH`

You can find the path to pod command by typing `which pod` on command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

This worked for me