# Jenkins cannot find Ionic CLI on Mac

Tags: jenkins, ionic-framework, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get Jenkins to build my Ionic project on my Mac Mini, but it errors out with:

```
line 1: ionic: command not found
script returned exit code 127
```

I have the following Jenkins file:

```
    pipeline {
      agent any,
      environment {
         PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
     }
      stages {
        stage('Starting') {
          steps {
            echo 'Starting'
          }
        }
        stage('npm install') {
          steps {
            sh 'npm install'
          }
        }
        stage('IOS Build') {
          steps {
            sh 'ionic cordova build ios --prod --release'
           } 
        }
      }
    }
```

Ionic should be in `/usr/local/bin`, eg if I get the following:

```
Dev-Mac-mini:bin Development$ which ionic
  /usr/local/bin/ionic
```

And if I run `ionic` from the command line it is found.

Lastly, the `npm` works fine.

Any ideas what it would not find the Ionic cli?

Comment: Try restarting jenkins agent if you are using master agent style of communication. Else restart the jenkins instance or service.

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use the version of ionic which you added as a dev dependency. And in Jenkinsfile you can invoke it like below.

```
sh "./node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic cordova build ios --prod --release"
```

Comment: Should still be able to use the globally installed CLI (I have it globally, and not local)

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905787/6437038

**TLDR**: add `#!/bin/bash -l` in the beginning of the jenkins job

Answer (score 0):

Try using `withEnv`:

```
withEnv([
  "PATH+LOCAL=/usr/local/bin"
]) {
  stage('IOS Build') {
    steps {
      sh 'ionic cordova build ios --prod --release'
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the above, but when I went to go into the Blue Ocean edit screen, I got There was an error loading the pipeline from the Jenkinsfile in this repository. Correct the error by editing the Jenkinsfile using the declarative syntax then commit it back to the repository.
 
expecting '}', found '' @ line 27, column 1.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it appears the `Blue Ocean` part of Jenkins does not like you editing the Jenkins file outside of it's own editor. This is what I was doing (just editing from the Gitlab editor). Perhaps I had some invisible characters, as I ended up even getting errors saying it did not like `agent any`!.

I deleted everything, and started again, and this time only edited from the Blue Ocean editor, and now the original script as in my question worked fine, ie it picked up the ionic cli from the PATH supplied.